# USERDATA being incorrectly carried over to other spool files

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I have an RPG program which executes the below command through QCMDEXC:

```
OVRPRTF FILE(QSYSPRT) HOLD(*YES) SAVE(*YES) USRDTA(OWNERUPD)
```

The program also executes a `DLTOVR FILE(QSYSPRT)` command through QCMDEXC. The issue is that the DLTOVR seems to fail occasionally and as a result, the USRDTA of spool files from programs executed afterwards appears as "OWNERUPD".

In order to fix this issue, I tried changing the scope of OVRPRTF to *CALLLVL. Also applied the same scope change to DLTOVR.
This seems to be working fine. The OVERRIDE now seems to be affecting only the program generating the spool. But my question is, would there be any "hidden" dangers in making this change?

If so, what would be a better approach?

Comment: I find overrides to be a headache.  My solution is to run all the programs and service programs in the same named activation group.

Answer (score 1):

If `*CALLLVL` made a difference, it would seem you are running in an actual ILE activation group rather than OPM (RPGIII) default activation group (DAG).

Another option would be to use `ACTGRP(*NEW)` on the ILE RPG program and leave `OVRSCOPE(*ACTGRPDFN)`.  You wouldn't even need the DLTOVR as the activation group and the override would disappear when the program returns.

However, use of `ACTGRP(*NEW)` is not a good idea if the program is called in a loop.

Last option, use `ACTGRP(<something>)` and `OVRSCOPE(*ACTGRPDFN)` so that the program and the override are in a specific activation group other than whatever activation group the rest of your programs run in.  (Likely the default QILE, which is a poor choice in the first place and entirely different than the OPM DAG.)

Basically, your other options require an understanding of how ILE Activation groups work.

Comment: Could you please tell me if there would be any issues with using *CALLLVL?

Comment: should be fine as long as you delete it when you are done.